# Confused by variable scope - destructor called unexpectedly

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, destructor

I have 3 classes, Fruit, Apple and Orange, with Fruit being the parent of both. I have a static method where I do the following:

```
int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) {
  Fruit listener;
  if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    listener = Apple(settings);
  } else {
    listener = Orange(settings);
  }
  return uv_run(listener.loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

What confuses me is that the destructor of Apple, which runs clean up code Fruit doesn't have, is called within the condition. Apple is a child of Fruit and Fruit is declared outside the condition so shouldn't the scope last until the return?

Comment: `Apple's` destructor would be called at the end of this line: `listener = Apple(settings);`. The RHS is a temporary that gets discarded after a *conversion* to `Fruit`. Also, look up *object slicing*.

Comment: You probably want to make `Fruit listener` a pointer (unless you have defined conversion operators for Apples and Oranges into Fruit).

Comment: One might add that the remedy is to use a pointer or a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a temporary of type `Apple`. It goes out of scope at the end of the expression that it is a part of - which is the assignment statement. When it goes out of scope, the destructor will get called. The hierarchical relationship between `Fruit` and `Apple` is irrelevant here.

If it helps, you can think of this block:

```
if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    listener = Apple(settings);
}
```

as basically equivalent to:

```
if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    Apple some_temporary_apple(settings);
    listener = std::move(some_temporary_apple);
}
```

which may make it clearer as to why `~Apple()` gets called at the end of the assignment.

Also note that:

```
Fruit f = Apple();
```

will perform [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/2069064), which makes it an anti-pattern.

Comment: Object Slicing - thanks, this turns out to be a bigger problem.

Comment: @lapinrigolo Yes. The type of polymorphism you want requires the use of pointers

Comment: @FélixCantournet That is incorrect: the type of polymorphism laprinrigolo is doing does not require pointers.  It cannot be done with values, but references are neither pointers nor values.  Sadly, it led the OP down a [bad path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194024/destructor-not-being-called-with-smart-or-raw-pointer/28194561#28194561)

Comment: @Yakk Yes, references could be used too (and preferably in this particular instance). I think the larger point was beware of object slicing.