# Destructor not being called with smart or raw pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Continuing from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192501/confused-by-variable-scope-destructor-called-unexpectedly):

On this code, the destructors for Apple and Fruit don't get called at all. I have `std::cerr` statements in both and there's some clean up code in Apple that doesn't run. I thought calling delete was enough? Am I doing RAII correctly? I've also replaced the raw pointer with std::unique_ptr and the same result.

```
int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) {
  Fruit *listener;
  if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    listener = new Apple(settings);
  } else {
    listener = new Orange(settings);
  }
  int r = uv_run(listener->loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  delete listener;
  return r;
}
```

**Update:**
All classes have virtual destructors.

Comment: Does `Fruit` have a virtual destructor? You've got undefined behaviour (probably manifesting as failure to call the correct destructor) otherwise.

Comment: @lapinrigolo The code you show is correct in terms of constructing and destroying instances. You may want to replace `listener.loop` with `listener->loop`.

Comment: Also, you really should use `std::unique_ptr`. Though it does not really matter if `uv_run` is `noexcept`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: or even no pointers: `int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) { if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    return uv_run(Apple(settings).loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  } else {
    return uv_run(Orange(settings).loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  } }`

Comment: Does *all classes* include `Fruit`... I know stupid question, just bear with me

Comment: With no full class definitions it's not really possible to tell anything.

Comment: This question is one vote away from being closed as off-topic, please add the necessary information for us to answer it, which means at least the destructor declaration for `Fruit`, preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure. Just wasn't sure that was all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your immediate problem almost certainly that is that `~Fruit()` is not `virtual`.  Add that (`virtual ~Fruit() = default` or `virtual ~Fruit() {}` to `class Fruit`) and your code (as posted) will magically start to work.

However that is not what your code should be.  Just working, well, not good enough.

There are a number of improvements you can make to your code.  As a first improvement we'll use a `unique_ptr`: (as @Deduplicator mentioned above in comments)

```
int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) {
  std::unique_ptr<Fruit> listener;
  if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    listener.reset( new Apple(settings) );
  } else {
    listener.reset( new Orange(settings) );
  }
  int r = uv_run(listener->loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  return r;
}
```

which uses RAII to ensure the lifetime of the listener is bounded.  Much better, no more manual `delete` (which could be missed by accident, or exception).

In C++14, the `.reset(new Blah(whatever))` can be replaced with `= std::make_unique<Blah>(whatever);`, and now your code never explicitly calls `new` and `delete`, which is a good habit to get into.  However your code is tagged C++11, so I'll leave the C++11 version up above.

While that is better, we can do best.  There is no need for using the free store (heap) at all.

A simple way to avoid the free store use is: (stolen from @Jarod in comments above)

```
int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) {
  if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    return uv_run(Apple(settings).loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  } else {
    return uv_run(Orange(settings).loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  }
}
```

which has the disadvantage of repeating the `uv_run` code (and can thus breed bugs).  We can fix this with a lambda:

```
int32_t Fruit::frutificate(const Settings& settings) {
  auto fruit_the_uv = [&](Fruit&& fruit) {
    return uv_run(fruit.loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  };
  if (settings.has_domain_socket()) {
    return fruit_the_uv( Apple(settings) );
  } else {
    return fruit_the_uv( Orange(settings) );
  }
}
```

where we factor out the common code into a lambda, and then invoke it on the two branches.  I used rvalue references as we are passing in temporary fruit.

Plus, `fruit_the_uv` reminds me of a [90s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV7aOnX7XeE) [rap song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfgG8HH2LN0) whenever I read it.  And that is a plus.

Comment: Nope, all destructors are virtual. I know I can fix this with your lambda but I'm now curious as to why the destructor wouldn't work.

Comment: @lapinrigolo Because you are passing in temporaries, and temporaries do not bind to lvalue references.  So I used an rvalue reference.  If a `const&` would work (ie, if `uv_run` with a `const` `loop` works), you can use that instead.  In C++14 I'd just use a forwarding reference (`auto&&`) probably.  -- so, `Fruit` has an explicit destructor, and it is `virtual`?  Post the actual destructor for `Fruit`.

Comment: `virtual ~Fruit();` - the implementation is empty.